# Syntax Error on while command in python 3 program

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in python 3. Made a program. it was working fine but then i change it a bit and now its giving syntax error on line 2 of give code.I have only uploaded a patch of total code

i tired retyping it. I also tried executing it on different IDEs. But nothing worked

```
print('You have a total of {} guesses'.format(len(answer))
while count < len(answer):
    guess = input('Enter the letter:  ')   #input of the guesses
    guess = guess.lower()   # all words are in lowercase
    count += 1
    print('You have {} guesses left'.format(len(answer)-count)  #to tell the total guess left
    # we need to iterate over the answer to check guess in answer
    for i in range(len(answer)):
        if answer[i] == guess:
            display[i] = guess     #replacing corresponding '_' with letter
    print(' '.join(display))
    if display == answer:   #to check and stop unneccessary repitations
        break
if display == answer:
    print('You Won!!!!')
else:
    print('You Lost!!!!')
again = input('Do you want to play again(Y/N)?'  )
if again.lower() == 'n':
    is_again = False
print('Good Bye!!!')
```

it is giving a syntax error on while command. it is like this:

```
while count < len(answer):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a parenthesis! The line:

```
print('You have {} guesses left'.format(len(answer)-count)
     ^----------------------------------------------------?
                                       ^-----------------^
                                           ^------^
```

is missing a matching parenthesis for the `print`. It should be:

```
print('You have {} guesses left'.format(len(answer)-count))
```

Your first line is missing a parenthesis as well:

```
print('You have a total of {} guesses'.format(len(answer))
```

Should be:

```
print('You have a total of {} guesses'.format(len(answer)))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. See the edited answer - your first line was also incorrect